# AS 3 know if only certain characters are inside a string

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

with AS3 is there a simple way to understand if a string is composed only with 2 characters? for instance binary number. Can I understand if the string that I am inspecting is composed only of 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick :

```
private function isBinary(str:String):Boolean 
{
    var binary:Boolean = true;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
    {
        if (str.charAt(i) != "0" && str.charAt(i) != "1")
        {
            binary = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return binary;
}
```